# Q. In SSAS - Referenced Relationship Type

Tags: sql-server, database, ssas, data-warehouse

In SSAS, Multidimensional Model has shown in the below image.  [image: fact-dimension model]

Users need to be able to analyze sales by color.
You need to create a dimension that contains all of the colors for products sold by the company.
Which relationship type should you use between the InternetSales table and the new dimension?

A. no relationship
B. regular
C. fact
**D. referenced**
E. many-to-many
F. data mining

Is it referenced Relationship?
The fact table is linked to the Colors dimension via another dimension named Products. It should be a referenced relationship. is it?

Answer (score 1):

If say referenced. Regular dimensions are joined direct to fact table. The others aren't applicable in this scenario.

Comment: I think it is a regular relationship.  Since the dimension with product and colors can be directly linked with the fact table, it becomes the relationship type regular. therefore it is not Referenced, It is Regular Relationship. 

Thanks.